# Extracting substring from inside bracketed string, where the substring may have spaces

Tags: sed, grep

I've got an application that has no useful api implemented, and the only way to get certain information is to parse string output. This is proving to be very painful...

I'm trying to achieve this in bash on SLES12.

---

Given I have the following strings:

```
QMNAME(QMTKGW01)                                          STATUS(Running)
```

```
QMNAME(QMTKGW01)                                          STATUS(Ended normally)
```

I want to extract the STATUS value, ie "Ended normally" or "Running". 
Note that the line structure can move around, so I can't count on the "STATUS" being the second field.

The closest I have managed to get so far is to extract a single word from inside STATUS like so

```
echo "QMNAME(QMTKGW01)  STATUS(Running)" | sed "s/^.*STATUS(\(\S*\)).*/\1/"
```

This works for "Running" but not for "Ended normally"

I've tried switching the \S* for [\S\s]* in both "grep -o" and "sed" but it seems to corrupt the entire regex.

Comment: Just wondering - in the output don't you also need to see which QNAME is associated with which STATUS? Just getting the STATUS but not being able to tell from which QNAME each STATUS came from seems like a big loss of information.

Comment: yeah, but it's the same query. This logic is actually in a seperate function where "STATUS" "QNAME" are passed as arguments. I just tried to code snippet here for clarity but I can't do that in a comment and make it readable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely a regex issue, by doing `\S` you requested to match non-white space characters within `(..)` but the failing case has a space between which does not comply with the grammar defined. Make it simple by explicitly calling out the characters to match inside `(..)` as `[a-zA-Z ]*` i.e. zero or more upper & lower case characters and spaces.

```
sed 's/^.*STATUS(\([a-zA-Z ]*\)).*/\1/'
```

Or use character classes `[:alnum:]` if you want numbers too

```
sed 's/^.*STATUS(\([[:alnum:] ]*\)).*/\1/'
```

Comment: oh, of course! I didn't appreciate that \S was explicitly excluding white space.
I've opted for the first option.

Thank you for the clean explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*STATUS(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/' file
```

Output:

```
Running
Ended normally
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting a substring matching a given pattern is a job for `grep`, not `sed`. We should use `sed` when we must **edit** the input string. (A lot of people use `sed` and even `awk` just to extract substrings, but that's wasteful in my opinion.)

So, here is a `grep` solution. We need to make some assumptions (in **any** solution) about your input - some are easy to relax, others are not. In your example the word `STATUS` is always capitalized, and it is immediately followed by the opening parenthesis (no space, no colon etc.). These assumptions can be relaxed easily. More importantly, and not easy to work around: there are no *nested* parentheses. You will want the longest substring of non-closing-parenthesis characters following the opening parenthesis, no mater what they are.

With these assumptions:

```
$ grep -oP '\bSTATUS\(\K[^)]*(?=\))' << EOF
> QMNAME(QMTKGW01)                                     STATUS(Running)
> QMNAME(QMTKGW01)                                     STATUS(Ended normally)
> EOF

Running
Ended normally
```

Explanation:

Command options: `o` to return only the matched substring; `P` to use Perl extensions (the `\K` marker and the lookahead). The regexp: we look for a word boundary (`\b`) - so the word STATUS is a complete word, not part of a longer word like SUBSTATUS; then the word STATUS and opening parenthesis. This is required for a match, but `\K` instructs that this part of the matched string will not be returned in the output. Then we seek zero or more non-closing-parenthesis characters (`[^)]*`) and we require that this be followed by a closing parenthesis - but the closing parenthesis is also not included in the returned string. That's a "lookahead" (the `(?= ... )` construct).

Comment: I've had issues before using lookaheads so I try to avoid them whenpossible.  
Either way, is there a process time benifit of doing this is grep as opposed to sed?  
  
In my real function "STATUS" is a string argument passed to a function, ie variable.  
This is because there are hundreds of fields that I may want/need to extract, but they all follow the same convention of having "THING(value)"

Comment: @SteveStevens - what kind of issues did you have before? Did they depend on `grep` version, or on user knowledge, or what? Passing in a variable instead of a literal string is a shell issue (and an easy one to handle). `grep` faster than `sed`: honestly, I don't know. I am almost certain that `grep` will be faster since it has less overhead, but I don't know **how much** faster. That may depend on the structure of your data. You can certainly experiment; if your data is really massive, save a chunk of the data in a test file for testing.